# Koa-mount/router + socket.io integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, koa, koa2

Out of curiosity I chose Koa2 for my home Node server. Unfortunately I got stuck on implementing websockets for client/server communication. In following app, socket.io client refuses to connect to its server part. Any idea/hints?

```
// main.js
const argv = require('yargs');
const app = require('./src/app');
const conf = require('./config');

const port = argv.port || process.env.PORT || conf.port || 3000;

app.listen(port);

console.log(`IOKvit Server is listening on port ${ port }...`);
```

.....................

```
// app.js
const Koa = require('koa');
const mount = require('koa-mount');
const router = require('./api');
const staticRoutes = require('./static');

const app = new Koa();

app.use(mount(staticRoutes));
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

const http = require('http');
const socket = require('socket.io');

const server = http.createServer(app.callback());
const io = new socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected')
});

module.exports = app;
```

.....................

```
// static.js
const Koa = require('koa');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const mount = require('koa-mount');
const path = require('path');

const staticApp = new Koa();
const root_dir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

staticApp.use(serve(root_dir + '/static', { maxage: 60 * 1000 }));
staticApp.use(mount('/lib/vue', serve(root_dir + '/node_modules/vue/dist/', { maxage: 60 * 1000 })));
staticApp.use(mount('/lib/vue-material', serve(root_dir + '/node_modules/vue-material/dist/', { maxage: 60 * 1000 })));
staticApp.use(mount('/lib/vue-router', serve(root_dir + '/node_modules/vue-router/dist/', { maxage: 60 * 1000 })));
staticApp.use(mount('/lib/socket.io', serve(root_dir + '/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/', { maxage: 60 * 1000 })));
staticApp.use(mount('/lib/roboto', serve(root_dir + '/node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/', { maxage: 60 * 1000 })));
staticApp.use(mount('/lib/material-icons-font', serve(root_dir + '/node_modules/material-icons-font/', { maxage: 60 * 1000 })));

module.exports = staticApp;
```

.....................

```
// api.js
const Router  = require('koa-router');
const house = require('./house').controller;

const router = new Router();

router.get('/rooms', house.list_rooms);
router.get('/rooms/:name', house.room);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you simplify this?  For example is the static bit necessary?  Are you serving the static resources?  Is the middleware moving past that point?

Comment: @akaphenom All static resources seem to be delivered without problems. Firstly, I wanted to host the static part using nginx, but that didn&#39;t seem to pass sockets through either. Yes, I've tried setting the needed values for socket passing in nginx's config.

Comment: I would n't complicate the server until you have the basics working (don't introduce nginx).  honestly I don't see anything overtly wrong.  I assume you are not getting the console log message on the socket conenction?

Comment: Whats the client bit look like?

Comment: @akaphenom Yup, exactly that + on the client, io() object returns "connected: false"

Comment: @akaphenom I've tried many different combinations. 

"const socket = io();"
"const socket = io.connect();"
"const socket = new io();"

I've tried all of them with var and let variable declarations.

Comment: This is what I have done with Koa 1:

const http = app.listen(port);
const io = socketIo.listen(http);
io.on("connection", function(socket){  })

Comment: Have you caught any exceptions?

Comment: @akaphenom Your solution seems to be working. I have no idea why, but it seems to be working. Thank you very much. If you&#39;d like, you can post it as an answer and I can choose it as the best Answer.

Comment: Glad to be able to help. I will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have leveraged code like this in Koa (1.0.0):

```
const koa = require("koa");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

const app = koa();
const port = 8000
const http = app.listen(port); 
const io = socketIo.listen(http); 

io.on("connection", function(socket){ 
  console.log("connected")
})
```